# How to use React Module CSS in Meteor 1.3 beta

Tags: meteor, reactjs, webpack, react-css-modules

**EDIT: Meteor 1.3 release is out and a [npm package](https://github.com/nathantreid/meteor-css-modules/) is about to be released allowing a direct use of CSS modules without Webpack**

---

I would like to use https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules in Meteor 1.3 via NPM. But the readme says to use Webpack. I never used Webpack as it seems to me to do the same build job as Meteor.

So do you know a way, in this specific case, for using React Module CSS in Meteor 1.3 beta?

Answer (score 3):

There is actually package for this. MDG is also considering bring webpacks on meteor core at some stage. And yes it is build tool. Just more modular and faster than current one. Its also pretty complex as build tools go, at least in my opinion.

To have webpacks in meteor just >

```
meteor add webpack:webpack
meteor remove ecmascript
```

You need to remove ecmascripts as you get them from webpack as well and having 2 installs can cause errors.

For much more complete answer check Sam Corcos blog post and also Ben Strahan's comment for Meteor 1.3 Beta. I used it as tutorial to get different webpack package up.

https://medium.com/@SamCorcos/meteor-webpack-from-the-ground-up-f123288c7b75#.phcq5lvm8

For package you mentioned I think `webpack.packages.json` should look something like this

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^2.0.6-beta",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.0.0-beta"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.15.0-alpha.1",
    "react-css-modules": "^3.7.4",
    "react-dom": "^0.15.0-alpha.1"
  }
```

And webpack.config.js you could copy directly from

https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules-examples/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: It is too early to say that Meteor is going to use Webpack. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hk0h_7-N9hA

Comment: I said considering , but I agree with comment. I hope not. Webpack does everything but its too complicated use and at least I never need 90 % features anyway

Comment: Thx for your answer Kimmo. But I would not even said "considering" since this post https://forums.meteor.com/t/is-meteor-dying-state-of-the-meteor-ecosystem/14967/69 where Benjamin (working at MDG on build part of Meteor) states why he disapproves Webpack way. However https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack/tree/master/packages/webpack/ is indeed now available for Meteor 1.3 since a few days. Unfortunately I don't need this package anymore and I don't have time to run a test. If you'd like to get the bounty, could u plz make a test and show result. I will accept your answer then.

Comment: I was just about to comment that hence its bounty question I would probably need to test it. I try find time tomorrow else someone can take the credits.

Comment: the bounty was automatically given to you because you got 2 upvotes. It is funny though that you got +125 and I got -250. The math is wrong =p

Comment: You are right zVictor maybe stackoverflow has started collecting transaction fees and forgot to tell anyone...

Answer (score 2):

Meteor v1.3.2 introduced built-in import functionality for `.css` files (as well as other CSS preprocessor files, such as `less` and `sass`) from within `.js` and `.jsx`.

For example, given the following (simplified) folder structure,

```
.
├── client
│   └── main.js
├── imports
│   └── client
│       ├── main.css
│       └── main.jsx
├── node_modules
│   └── some-module
│       └── dist
│           └── css
│               └── main.css
├── package.json
└── server
    └── main.js
```

where `some-module` is an npm module installed using:

```
$ meteor npm install --save some-module
```

importing local and module stylesheets in `imports/client/main.jsx`:

```js
// importing a style file from a node module
import 'some-module/dist/css/main.css';

// importing a style from a local file
import './main.css';
```

Comment: It will only attach css contents from those files to the 'head' tag, but you can modify this functionality to achieve something like css modules. Take a look at this experiment: https://github.com/juliancwirko/meteor-css-modules-test

Answer (score 1):

You can start from scratch like this.

## Start from scratch

```
meteor create test-project
cd test-project
npm init
meteor remove ecmascript
meteor add webpack:webpack
meteor add webpack:react
meteor add webpack:less
meteor add react-runtime # Skip this step if you want to use the NPM version
meteor add react-meteor-data
meteor
npm install
meteor
```

## Entry files

Your entry files are defined within your package.json. The main is your server entry and the browser is your client entry.

```
{
  "name": "test-project",
  "private": true,
  "main": "server/entry.js",
  "browser": "client/entry.js"
}
```

For more info please check this [link](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack/tree/master/packages/webpack/)