# Using Bootstrap with Meteor 1.3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Why can't I simply download the bootstrap scss files after installing the seba:minifiers-autoprefixer and fourseven:scss packages and use them in my react component just like that?

Comment: What Meteor version are you using? v1.3.2 [should allow you to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36657832/268093).

Comment: I am using v 1.3.2

Comment: You can do that, that's exactly what I'm doing in my projects.